# Why do all wireless mice have unresponsive movements with my computer?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

My Dell desktop computer doesn't seem to be able to work well with wireless mouse. I've tried 3 different 2.4ghz wireless mice so far, and they all appear jerky. The cursor would stutter and is not very responsive when I move my mouse. These wireless mice work perfectly fine and are very responsive when I connect them to my laptop or my friends' computers. So the mice they no problem on their own.

My desktop computer, however, has no issues with Bluetooth wireless mouse. I had one before it stopped working and I didn't have those movement issues.

Thinking that this could be due to signal interruption, I've tried turning off my wifi internet, disabling bluetooth, switching off routers and keeping my phone away from the mouse, but none of these have helped.

Also, this happens to wireless keyboards (that don't use bluetooth) too. My keystrokes will either be missed or show up 2-3 seconds later.

I cannot understand how this happens. What could have caused my computer to not work well with 2.4ghz wireless mouse? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Consider reinstalling any drivers related to Bluetooth.

Comment: @MichaelBailey My computer has no problem with mice connected through Bluetooth. It only has issues with mice using 2.4ghz wireless connection. Would reinstalling drivers related to Bluetooth help in this case?

Comment: Ah. Nevermind. Am not familiar with 2.4ghz mouses at all, sorry.

Comment: I have never owned a wireless mouse that didn't start to act funky, with terrible latency, after a few hours of use.  Even on brand new installations of Windows 7. Microsoft, Logitech, it didn't matter. After a few hours, they become useless, and seem to develop a mind of their own. If I didn't hate wires so much, I'd have thrown them against a brick wall already.  This has happened on multiple machines.